# Get Centroid from Sequence in N-Dimensions

Tags: python, centroid

I am trying to get the centroid for a series in n-dimensions.

This is what I have tried:

```
def get_centroid(point1, point2):
    return sum((q + p) / 2 for p, q in zip(point1, point2))

p = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

q = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

get_centroid(p, q)
Out[18]: 31.5
```

But what I am trying to get is:

```
Out[]: [1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5]
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why does `get_centroid` return a sum?

Comment: Because I am still new to all this, and I am trying to figure it out. lol Fair point though. I just thought that if it was in the square brackets it would return each the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension instead of `sum` function because:

1. `sum` returns the sum of all elements of an iterable, so it is now returning the sum of the averages
2. Instead you need average of the corresponding values in each list/points
3. List comprehension creates a list of values, each value given by the formula you have already written for find the average

Try the following:

**Code**

```
def get_centroid(point1, point2):
    return [(q + p) / 2 for p, q in zip(point1, point2)]

p = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

q = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

print(get_centroid(p, q))
```

**Output**

```
[1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5]
```

Comment: Brilliant! So, just for my own clarity, if I am trying to return a list, I should start the argument with a square bracket? I get why the sum () is wrong. I just mean as a general rule.

Comment: @Noob3000, Yes I've added a brief explanation, this method is called list comprehension. Or you could create an empty list and append each newly calculated value to it.